# How to get search result as image rather than page

Tags: search

so I'm making a meme template(image) website . But when i try to search a template the search result show the page it is in rather than actually showing the template(image). What can i so do to show search result as  image specified.

Comment: You can probably just create or edit the search.php template in your theme or child theme to show search results how you want. Are these the featured images on the pages?

Comment: Have you looked into the `search.php` template?